# devise_token_auth , bcrypt check equality on tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, token, bcrypt

I'm using the devise_token_auth Gem to build a public API.
To destroy a session (sign_out) i have to send : uid (mail), client_id, and access-token (associated with this client_id)

This method from **devise_token_auth gem** checks if token is still available, and if it is valid. [Github code](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/models/devise_token_auth/concerns/user.rb)

```
def token_is_current?(token, client_id)
# ghetto HashWithIndifferentAccess
expiry     = self.tokens[client_id]['expiry'] || self.tokens[client_id][:expiry]
token_hash = self.tokens[client_id]['token'] || self.tokens[client_id][:token]

return true if (
  # ensure that expiry and token are set
  expiry and token and

  # ensure that the token has not yet expired
  DateTime.strptime(expiry.to_s, '%s') > Time.now and

  # ensure that the token is valid
  BCrypt::Password.new(token_hash) == token
)
```

end

I have some issues with this line `BCrypt::Password.new(token_hash) == token`

What i know is :

- token_hash is the token extracted from DB
- token came from header of the request
- the line is using bcrypt "==" method to compare, which is

  def ==(secret);
        super(BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(secret, @salt));
      end

Since its using this method to check equality, the check doesn't pass, unless i explicity checking strings values.

Why use Bcrypt to compare two tokens, and not simply compare two strings.
Reading this : [bcrypt ruby doc](http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/classes/BCrypt/Password.html) i understand the point of using bcrypt for passwords but why for tokens ?